# Iterar um array até o fim a partir de um determinado índice gerado randomicamente - PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Boa noite pessoal.

Eu tenho um array com algumas paradas de ônibus com as seguintes informações:

```
array:9 [▼
0 => array:4 [▼
"id" => 35
"nome" => "Parada 35 - Copacabana"
"endereco_completo" => "Rua Copacabana"
"tempo" => 5
]
1 => array:4 [▼
"id" => 36
"nome" => "Parada 36 - Copacabana"
"endereco_completo" => "Rua Copacabana"
"tempo" => 11
]
2 => array:4 [▼
"id" => 37
"nome" => "Parada 37 - Copacabana"
"endereco_completo" => "Rua Copacabana"
"tempo" => 7
]
3 => array:4 [▼
"id" => 38
"nome" => "Parada 38 - Boa Viagem"
"endereco_completo" => "Rua Vinte de Janeiro"
"tempo" => 12
]
4 => array:4 [▼
"id" => 39
"nome" => "Parada 39 - Boa Viagem"
"endereco_completo" => "Rua Vinte de Janeiro"
"tempo" => 6
]
5 => array:4 [▼
"id" => 40
"nome" => "Parada 40 - Boa Viagem"
"endereco_completo" => "Rua Barão de Souza Leão"
"tempo" => 7
]
6 => array:4 [▼
"id" => 41
"nome" => "Parada 41 - Boa Viagem"
"endereco_completo" => "Rua Barão de Souza Leão"
"tempo" => 7
]
7 => array:4 [▼
"id" => 42
"nome" => "Parada 42 - Boa Viagem"
"endereco_completo" => "Rua Barão de Souza Leão"
"tempo" => 11
]
8 => array:4 [▼
"id" => 43
"nome" => "Parada 43 - Boa Viagem"
"endereco_completo" => "Rua Barão de Souza Leão"
"tempo" => 11
]
```

O meu objetivo primeiramente é selecionar uma parada randomicamente neste array. Após selecionada, eu quero pegar a soma dos tempos de cada uma parada a partir desta parada selecionada randomicamente (ignorando as anteriores).

Estou fazendo o seguinte para selecionar essa parada randômica:

```
foreach ($arrayParadas as $key => $value) {
        $pegarParadaRandomica = rand($key, 1);
    }
```

Com isso eu tenho o índice do array de uma parada randômica, mas não estou conseguindo fazer o restante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para selecionar a parada onde vai começar basta usar o [`rand`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rand.php)(que você já estava a usar) de `0` ao tamanho das paradas menos uma, que lhe vai dar a posição de inicio:

```
$indiceParadaInicial = rand(0, count($arrayParadas) - 1);
```

É necessário que o segundo parâmetro seja `tamanho-1` pois o valor de fim é para geração do randomico é inclusivo, e como estamos a gerar posições, a posição correspondente ao tamanho já estaria fora do array.

Depois basta utilizar um `for` normal, já que o seu array é composto por indices numéricos a começar em `0`.

Exemplo:

```
$tempoTotal = 0;

for ($i = $indiceParadaInicial; $i < count($arrayParadas); ++$i){
    $tempoTotal += $arrayParadas[$i]["tempo"];
}
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/wwLT7p)

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu estava querendo fazer, muito bacana a sua resposta Isac, valeu